# How to clear the values of a key in Redis HyperLogLog

Tags: redis, hyperloglog

I'm using Redis implementation of HyperLogLog to count distinct values for given keys.

The keys are based on hour window. After the calendar hour changes, I want to reset the count of incoming values. I don't see any direct API for 'clearing' up the values through Jedis.

SET cannot be used here because it would corrupt the hash. Is there a way to correctly "reset" the count for a given key?

Answer (score 2):

Use the [`DEL`](http://redis.io/commands/del) command to delete the key, which will effectively reset the count.